# How do I migrate certificates for my AIR application that uses a native installer?

Tags: air, adobe, flex4.5

I have an Adobe AIR application that I package in a native installer for Windows. I just got a new certificate to sign it with and signing it with the new certificate works fine. However if I try to install it on a computer that has a previous version I get an error that the installer has been misconfigured.

[image: Installer misconfigured error]

If I uninstall the previous version, the installation works fine.

I've looked at the ADT tool and there is a -migrate ([Adobe docs](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/air/build/WS901d38e593cd1bac1e63e3d128fc240122-7ffd.html)) option where you first package and sign an air file with the new certificate and then use the adt -migrate command to sign the air file with the migration (old) certificate. But this won't work because I'm not able to package my app to a .air file since it uses NativeProcess.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was finally able to use the adt -migrate command. I had to remove the  tag from my program-app.xml file. After I did that, I was able to package to an air file without getting an error about the supported profiles. I followed the Adobe docs for the rest of the packaging process and this time installing over the old version didn't result in any errors.

Comment: Which tag did you remove from program-app.xml?

Comment: How did you get -migrate to work? I've tried this all different ways but can't find anything that works. What tag did you remove? What are you using to compile? The directions seem straightforward. First sign the air app with the new certificate. Then sign it again using the migrate command and the old certificate. Either nothing happens (via ant build) or I get an error at the command line. Nothing gives me any leads.